# Description CRS EPSG:6372

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

does someone know where could I find a description of CRS EPSG:6372. I searched in the EPSG page but seem not to find something that quick..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can seach in the EPSG geodetic parameter dataset here: https://epsg.org/

Search for 6372 on *the retrieve by* code tab.

[image]

Comment: EPSG registry is now at epsg.org